# git command to return non-zero if local branch is not same as remote

Tags: git

I am writing some automation to set up a release process (from git repository to a central release area).

The script will accept a working directory (local clone) and a tag as input. It will go into the working directory, **ensure that there are no changes to be pulled or pushed or resolved etc.** and then create the tag and push the tag to remote. The rest of the script will simply archive the tag straight from remote into destination directory.

Is there a git command which will let me automate the step in bold above? Some command that returns a non-zero code if local is not absolutely same as remote, that way I can stop the script at that point.

Comment: maybe you can use git cherry with sed or something to interpret the output?

Comment: I used in the past `git status --porcelain --branch`. With a modern `git` version, `git status --porcelain=v2 --branch` will be easier.

Comment: You could do a "git diff" on the branches and pipe the output to the unix "wc -l"  command. A count of 0 means there are no changes, non-zero count means there are changes to be pushed.

Comment: Yeah that was the first thing I thought of doing. But comparing checksums seems to be ideal. Also, git diff will still not tell me whether I am behind or ahead of remote, would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exact commands may depend on your configuration; I'm assuming a fairly typical set-up:

First, you have to make sure your local reference to the remote branch is up to date

```
git fetch
```

Now you need to know whether the reference to the remote branch is pointing to the same commit as the local branch.  (You *could* try to make the comparison content-based, but I don't recommend it.  If the commit is the same then the content is the same; if the commit is different, then even if the content is the same it's still probably the wrong place for the tag.)

So one simple way (in bash) would be

```
test `git rev-parse branch` = `git rev-parse origin/branch`
```